# How can I implement a joint hyerprior?

Tags: pymc3

I'm trying to recreate results from Bayesian Data Analysis Third Edition.

Chapter 5 Section 3 concerns tumors in rats.  a Hierarchical model is fit and the hyperprior used is not one of the densities included in pymc3.

The hyperprior is `a*b*(a+b)^-2.5`.  Here is my attempt using pymc3.

```
import pymc3 as pm
with pm.Model() as model:

    def ab_dist(x):
        #Should be log density, from what I have read
        a = x[0]
        b = x[1]
        return a+b-5/2*(a+b)

    ab = pm.DensityDist('ab', ab_dist, shape = 2, testval=[2,2])

    a = ab[0]
    b = ab[1]

    theta = pm.Beta('theta',alpha = a,beta = b)

    Y= pm.Binomial('y', n = n, p = theta, observed = y)
```

At this stage, I am returned an error

```
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[0] = 71, input[1].shape[0] = 20000)
```

What have I done wrong?  Have I correctly implemented the density?